# Evaluate $ \lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{ \left(\arctan(2x)-2\arctan( x)\right)^x}{\mathrm e^{x^2}-1-\sin^2(x)}$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

It is obvious that we use Taylor’s expansion. But what shall I do with the power of $x$ in numerator? In denominator I expand $\sin^2(x)$ as multiplying two expanded $\sin$?

Comment: are you sure that a Limit exists?

Comment: Please check the numerator. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks like if you evaluate $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} (\arctan 2x - 2\arctan x)^x$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} e^{x^2} - 1 - \sin^2 x$ separately you will get the numerator going to something non zero while the denominator goes to 0.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: @СемёнЮрченко If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: @СемёнЮрченко Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in other answer the numerator makes sense only when $x\to 0^{-}$. Putting $x=-t$ we can see that the numerator can be expressed as $$\left(\arctan\left(\frac{2t^{3}}{1+3t^{2}}\right)\right)^{-t} $$ Next we will make use of the following standard limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan x} {x} =1,\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x}=1$$ Let $z=2t^3/(1+3t^{2})$ and then $z\to 0^{+}$ and we can write the numerator as $$\left(\frac{\arctan z} {z} \right) ^{-t}\cdot \frac{(1+3t^{2})^{t}}{2^{t}(t^t)^{3}}$$ Via the above mentioned standard limits we can see that the numerator tends to $1$ as $t\to 0^{+}$. The denominator clearly tends to $0$ and remains positive therefore the desired limit is $\infty$. Most textbooks would say that the limit does not exist or the expression diverges to $\infty $.

Comment: It's not so clear to me how apply the standard limits, could you please add some details. Meanwhile +1 for faith!

Comment: @gimusi: see the updated answer.

Comment: in this case the use of standard limits is not so clear to me, maybe because I'm not so used to it for this kind of limits. For example, you are applying $x^x\to 1$ to $\left(\frac{\arctan z} {z} \right) ^{-t}$ but maybe shouldn't you exibit how you can assimilate the two limits?

Comment: @gimusi: the arctan ratio tends to $1$ and thus we get $1^{0}=1$.

Comment: Of course, forgive my stupid request of clarification! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**  Use $[f(x)]^{g(x)}=\mathrm{e}^{g(x)\log f(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the numerator part :**

$$(\arctan2x-2\arctan x)^x = e^{x\ln(\arctan2x-2\arctan x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that since

$$\arctan 2x-2\arctan x=2x-\frac{8x^3}{3}-2x+\frac{2x^3}{3}+o(x^3)=-2x^3+o(x^3)$$

the limit is well defined only for $x\to0^-$.

To handle with positive quantities set $x=-y$ with $y\to0^+$.

Thus:

$$\frac{\left(\arctan 2x -2\arctan x\right)^x}{\mathrm e^{x^2}-1-\sin^2x}=\frac{\left( \arctan(-2y)-2\arctan(-y)\right)^{-y}}{\mathrm e^{y^2}-1-\sin^2 (-y)}=\frac{\left( 2\arctan y-\arctan 2y\right)^{-y}}{\mathrm e^{y^2}-1-\sin^2 y}$$

$$\left( 2\arctan y-\arctan 2y\right)^{-y}=\left(2y^3+o(y^3)\right)^{-y}=e^{-y\log(2y^3+o(y^3))}\to e^0=1$$

and:

$$e^{y^2}-1-\sin^2 y=1+y^2+\frac{y^4}{2}+o(y^4)-1-\left(y-\frac{y^3}{6}+o(y^3)\right)^2=y^2+\frac{y^4}{2}+o(y^4)-y^2+\frac{y^4}{3}+o(y^4)=\frac{5y^4}{6}+o(y^4)\to 0$$

Finally:

> $$\frac{\left(\arctan 2x -2\arctan x\right)^x}{\mathrm e^{x^2}-1-\sin^2x}\to +\infty$$